# Django UserCreationForm with custom form not working

Tags: django-forms, django-registration

```
I have a custom template where you have to put (first_name, last_name, email, password1, password2) for registration --> no username. I tried to use CserCreationForm in the below form but it is not workin, at the end after feeding up the form with data, nothing happens by clicking on submit. Could you please advice where is the problem? Thanks in advance guys!
```

forms.py - I created SignUpForm inheriting from USerCreationForm, I need placeholders thus__init_ method

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Imie'
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Nazwisko'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Email'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Hasło'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Powtórz Hasło'


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        user.username = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py - here I'm using what django offers:)

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
   form_class = SignUpForm
   template_name = "register.html"
   success_url = "login"
```

template:I had a template where there were several fields to be filled in, as mentioned on the top, thus I am not using the simple {{form.as_table}, and username is not mandatory name, it should be the same as first_name

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
  <body>
  {% block header %} {% endblock %}
  {% block slogan %} {% endblock %}
    <section id = "register" class="login-page">
      <h2>Załóż konto</h2>
      <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.first_name}}
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            {{form.last_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.email}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.password1}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.password2}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group--buttons">
          <a href="login.html" class="btn btn--without-border">Zaloguj się</a>
          <button class="btn" type="submit">Załóż konto</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </body>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
  path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name = "register")
```

Comment: I think you do not need to set first_name etc. manually in save method. But you should encrypt the password within this save method like:
`user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma after the 'password2'.
class Meta:
model = User
fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )

Anyways you should put the name of the function that you call in the form's action.
It should be something like this.

```
 <section id = "register" class="login-page">
  <h2>Załóż konto</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: Hi fukurowl, thanks for your hint with the comma but it doesn't help, still nothing happens after clicking submit, I left the action empty because I don't want to be redirected to login page if the user is not created but I know what you meant by that. Thanks anyway, I am still ftrying to solve my issue with the code.